# Backbone collection recursively repeats itself

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, recursion, collections

```
var MyMod = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        someField: "123"    
    }
});

var MyCol = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyMod
});

var mod1 = new MyMod({someField: "222"});
var mod2 = new MyMod({someField: "333"});
var mod3 = new MyMod({someField: "555"});

var myCol = new MyCol();

myCol.add(mod1);
myCol.add(mod2);
myCol.add(mod3);

console.log(myCol);
```

I don't understand what's wrong with this code. When I inspect the resulted collection in debugger or console.log it has some weird recursive structure - it has models, each of which has collection of models, each of which has collection of same models - and so on.
Here's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GSt4G/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models have a `collection` property which is always set when a model is added to a collection for the first time. As a result, loving the collection logs each model, which necessarily logs the collection again... Etc.

If you want to log the contents of the collection, you could use the `toJSON()` method, which returns a plain array of plain objects containing the models' attributes by default.

```
console.log(myCol.toJSON());
```

Comment: OK, so this is the normal behaviour and I shouldn't worry about it? Thanks, I thought I did something wrong!)

Comment: Yeah, it's normal. `toJSON()` is much more useful for logging anyway unless you were burning to see the event handlers or whatnot. :-)